# Can I use my ADA at any time while they are staked into a pool or are they frozen?

Tags: stake-pool, ada, yoroi

Can I send my ADA to another wallet instantly or use them instantly for whatever reason I like while they are delegated(staked) into a pool in Yoroi Wallet or does it take time to undelegate them first etc? I don't mind losing rewards or the fee. I am just asking about the time needed.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is **no lock** on your funds while they are delegated, therefore you are free to do with your Ada as you please. There is also no timing consideration either. One note with that, any rewards that you have earned will need to be withdrawn to be able to transfer/use them. Yoroi let's you do this with a click of a button.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. 

I have one more question. What does the "costs 2.50% +340" for example, mean?

Comment: That is how much of the total rewards the pool operator gets per epoch if the pool creates a block. So if a pool creates 1 block, the total rewards would be around 600ada. The pool gets 340 ada and then 2.5% of the remainder. This is to reward them for participating in running the network. If the pool made 3 blocks it would be about 1800 ads total rewards, the pool gets 340 ada and 2.5% of what is left. Everything else goes to the delegators. Hope that helps!

Comment: Yep it helped a lot. Thank you very much!!

Comment: One final question about Sundaeswap. Do you believe that it is better to stake your ADA in one of the winning pools in order to get SS rewards or keep them ready to swap directly when the SS launches? Does the pool rewards going to be the same proportionally with the amount that you will be able to swap at the lowest price or how this is going to work? Why should I stake my ADA for a few amount of SS rewards instead of trading them instantly for more SS?

Comment: I actually applied to be a SS pool (didn't win), but as of today, the details on this are unknown. I think it will really depend on what your goals are. If you stake with a SS pool, you get to keep your Ada and earn rewards.

Comment: Sorry to hear that Pal and thanks for your reply. Let's see what will happen.